# Is this a good approach to add same background image for login page and other page

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, android

I am confused, because I want to create an app with real designs suggested by Google, for that I am using `Google + design / Google 4.4 kitkat design` .

I am designing an Android app, in which I have created my `login & already_logined` page, in both these pages I have added this image so backgrounds for `login & already_logined` ...

[image: login/alreadylogined activity background]

... but after `login & already_logined` page there is a main page where I have to show my actual data of the app, for that I am creating this design, but I am not happy with it

[image: my_main_data_activity_background]

Can you please suggest me a proper way to add background image for the app how to sense that which image will be perfect for the designing scenario!

Comment: Flagging this question for migration to stackoverflow since this is more of an implementation question rather than UX related

Comment: @MervinJohnsingh , i have posted this Question there , but they( 3 community guys ) told me post this question here .

Comment: what is your view , if ask this question to you , as your student .

Comment: Your question is vague. Are you asking for how to implement it or how to design it?

Comment: This should be on graphic design tbh.

Comment: Are you asking "what code do I need to add a background image" or are you asking "should I have a background image and, if so, what should it be?". For the former, that's a StackExchange question. For the latter, it's likely a GraphicDesign.SE question. But it's also quite vague and highly based on opinion, so may not be a great question there.

Comment: @DA01 - I think you mean ***StackOverflow***, not ***StackExchange***. =D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're getting a false sense of emptiness on the page by failing to include actual data in your mockup, specifically user avatars.
Once proper photos and names are added to your list view I think the level of visual stimulation will reach what you're going for.

Also keep in mind that you're probably the only person who will ever judge the app from a purely aesthetic sense - real users only care about achieving some task and just want the design to not get in their way.

Comment: Real users may not make a big fuss about aesthetics, however they do judge the aesthetics (and within 50ms too!) and even though they may not realise it, that judgement on aesthetics has an impact on their sense of the usability of the app. http://www.nature.com/news/2006/060109/full/news060109-13.html

Comment: That initial assessment is handled on the visually-attentive splash screen. My point is that it seemed to me that the op was stepping back from a use case and examining the list view as a purely graphic/visual element. I see this very often and attribute it to PowerPoint syndrome - the examination of experiential technology as screenshots on a slide. The average "design" conversation is weighted far closer to that use case than the screen's context within the broader experience.

Comment: Real users absolutely care about aesthetics. They may not articulate it that way, but it's key part of any app.

Comment: Yes, but they don't step back from a screen and say "how do I feel about the way this looks?"

Answer (score 4):

For your second screen I see you've carried over the background image in the top edge, but that's all.

You could carry forward the entire image, showing only the bits that peek out between each of the data panes. This way you establish a sense of branding, and enliven the data screen.

[image]